# unable to find ColorBox in CSS in ASP.NET and VB.NET Website

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, vb.net, colorbox

I've just been asked to look at a website, the previous developer hasn't documented anything nor has he commented the site at all.

I can see he's using ColorBox See below, I need to change its behavior.

```
<span class="pull-right">
    <span data-bind="visible: Score > 0, text: 'score: ' + Score"
        class="score hover-glow"
        data-placement="bottom" rel="tooltip"
        title="current score"></span>
    <a class="hover-glow colorbox"
        data-placement="bottom" rel="tooltip"
        title="view cv"
        data-bind="attr: { 'href': 'cv-preview.aspx?c=' + CvId }">
        <i class=" icon icon-file "></i>
    </a>
    <a class="hover-glow"
        data-placement="bottom" rel="tooltip"
        title="change status"
        data-bind="attr: { 'href': 'update-status_popup.aspx?i=' + Id + '&c=' + StatusId }">
        <i class="icon icon-random"></i>
    </a>
</span>
```

However I can't find a colorbox.css or any css file with references to ColorBox in it.

I'm a bit stumped and would welcome any help.

Thanks so far to those who suggested advice. I want to elaborate a bit more .

As you can see in the above code there are two links. one link will allow to view cv and another link will allow to change the update status (the website is a online portal for employers to manage the job application in their company).

Currently when some one is clicking on "view cv" a popup window is opened and user can view CV in the popup window. And when user clicks on "Change status" it goes to a different page to change the particular application status.

The requirement is to open the "change status" window also in a popup window. I could do that by changing the class from "hover glow" to "hover glow colorbox" But problem is the rquirement is having two different type of popup. The popup currently used in here is disabling the parent window. but in the 2nd popup it is required to keep the parent window active while the popup is open.

i have found one reference of colorbox though it is for different popup opening. the code is

```
            $.colorbox({ width: "900px", height: "80%", href: "/employer/help.aspx", iframe: true, open: true, overlayClose: true });
```

how I shall change the property of the colorbox

thanks

Comment: Do a global project search for `.colorbox` - find anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a global search by pressing ctrl+shift+F and select Entire solution in the select criteria and "colorbox" in the search text.

Answer (score 1):

Use browser tools (F12 in IE\Chrome, or FireBug in FireFox for example) or Fiddler, and turn on HTTP Traffic capturing.  Then, on any page where your ColorBox.css is being loaded, hit Ctrl+F5 (to ignore files in your browser cache).  In your network capture, you should see this CSS file and the path to it.  Here's an example on how to do this via IE dev tools: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg130952(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg130952%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)